# member not listed or available for github Allow specified actors to bypass required pull requests

Tags: github

Ive created a member in our github organisation and would like to use them for `Allow specified actors to bypass required pull requests` but for some reason they do not appear in the list of possible users. I can see other `members` as well as `admins` though so not sure why they are not listed?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i was rather stupid on this one.

I didn't give the member any permissions, so it couldn't access any repos. After adding it to the standard write group, everything worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Is the member you created "private" to the organization?

If the repository is internal the member is not visible in the search. Changing your repository to "public" will help you...although I see this as being a problem for the organization's "setup".

If your member is "private", you may need to add it to the repository inorder for it to be listed.